# How come Django allows user to enter <script>alert("hello")</script> in form CharField without throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, python, django, xss

I am new to Django and in my Django application, I have a model that contains the basic information about a vehicle (name, model, make, year). I add the information through a form. The issue is that if the user were to enter "alert("error")" then the form will allow it and it will be saved as valid input. So when the page refreshes, there will be an alert on the page and the field will now be blank. How to I prevent the user from entering JavaScript in the CharField?

I do not have 'autoescape off' anywhere in the code base nor do I use the 'safe' keyword in the html. I do not have the 'def clean' checking for such input as I was under the impression that Django would take care of such injection. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Django templates? If not how do you convert the data from the user/database to text on the screen?

Comment: @HenryWoody I am using Django templates, and the weird thing is I see the alert when I display it on one of my datatables. I have multiple tables but only one shows the alert. I was also informed that my ajax call has the flag "processData: false" and therefore not escaping the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly valid input. But it *won't* result in an alert on the page - because Django automatically escapes *output*.

Comment: The thing is the alert does display, but not everywhere. Only when one of my datatables contains the script. I mentioned to @HenryWoody that I was also informed that it may be because my ajax call that saves the information to the database has the flag value "processData: false" and therefore not encoding the data and resulting in the script alert displaying. My workaround at the moment is to explicitly call the escape() function on the variable with the alert script.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolve using strip_tags() functions

try this

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

string_value = "<b>Iam </b> <button>Nancy</button> moree. <span>Thanks</span>"
sanitize_value = strip_tags(string_value)
print(sanitize_value)
```

Note:

If you are using `strip_tags()`, then you should update your django to at least version Django 1.6 and 1.7 and above. This is
 because security experts found a way in order to bypass strip_tags in django version lower than version 1.6. see

[source link](https://www.mehmetince.net/django-strip_tags-bypass-vulnerability-exploit/)

**Solution 2:**

If you are using django templates,
You can also try this striptags template filter() at  your view
.

```
{{ value|striptags }}
```

if value is `"<b>Iam </b> <button>Nancy</button> moree. <span>Thanks</span>"`

the output will be "**I am Nancy Moree. Thanks**".

[source link](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags)

**solution 3:**

you can also python bleach library via clean() method 
[source](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html)